# Should I use window.alert() or just alert()?

Tags: javascript, methods

Javascript newbie here. Sometimes, `alert()` gives me the same result like `window.alert()`, just like `document.write()` and `write()`, for example.

So is it better to write the method in full length, or shortened?

Thanks!

Comment: The variable `window` is a global that refers to the inferred global object you are using. `window.alert()` and `alert()` are the same method calls.

Comment: I'd say it is better to use `window.alert()` as it explicitly says what context your script should be executed in !